# Java Bean Validation: Posible to specify runtime validations?

Tags: java, spring

I am maintaining a web app that is using Java bean validations (as part of JSR303 I believe).

Members are mapped with annotations like `@Pattern` and then we have a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` that performs the validation. The Validator that this factory bean bootstraps is actually the Hibernate validation instance.

My problem is that my `@Pattern` regex needs to be loaded at runtime when my application starts up, so I cannot use the annotation.

Therefore, I'm wondering if there is an alternative way such as XML to plug in such validation?

If not, I may just have to use a separate Spring validator to do this work

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating custom validator as described in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html#validation.beanvalidation.spring.constraints. Thus you will need to check the value agains the pattern in the code of constraint validator class.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure bean validation using [XML](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#xml) for such a thing. The syntax is a lot like the JavaBean XML format and maps rather well to the hierarchical structure of the equivalent Java syntax.